# bitmap exceeds 32 bits error with createScaledBitmap in android

Tags: android

When calling the following method:

```
 Bitmap localBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(paramBitmap, 360, (int)(360.0D / (paramBitmap.getWidth() / paramBitmap.getHeight())), false);
```

I get the exception trace as:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bitmap size exceeds 32 bits

I printed the size of incoming bitmap using statements:

```
  System.out.println("paramBitmap.getWidth() "+ paramBitmap.getWidth());
  System.out.println("paramBitmap.getHeight() "+ paramBitmap.getHeight());
```

and it is 480x960

How to debug this problem and solve it.

Answer (score 0):

i know its late but it might help somebody,I faced the same problem when i tried to draw a border for bitmap and rotate it to certain angle, it always crashed in **xiaomi mi** mobile, i solved it by scaling the bitmap as per the need,

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);
final int BORDER_WIDTH = 10;
final int BORDER_COLOR = Color.YELLOW;
Bitmap res = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp.getWidth() + 2 * BORDER_WIDTH,bmp.getHeight() + 2 * BORDER_WIDTH,bmp.getConfig());
Canvas c = new Canvas(res);
Paint p = new Paint();
p.setColor(BORDER_COLOR);
c.drawRect(0, 0, res.getWidth(), res.getHeight(), p);
p = new Paint(Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG);
c.drawBitmap(bmp, BORDER_WIDTH, BORDER_WIDTH, p);
float viewWidth = (float) res.getWidth();
float viewHeight = `enter code here`(float) res.getHeight();
float ratiowidth = vi`enter code here`ewWidth / (float) res.getWidth();
float ratioheight = viewHeight / (float) res.getHeight();
Matrix mat = new Matrix();
mat.postScale(ratiowidth, ratioheight);
mat.postRotate(45);
Bitmap bMapRotate = Bitmap.createBitmap(res, 0,0,res.getWidth(),res.getHeight(), mat, true);
```